# Using enum in loops and value consistency

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I'm a big fan of C++'s strong-typing features and what I like the most is to use enumerations while dealing with limited sets of data.

But enumerations lack some useful features, for example operators:

```
enum class Hex : int
{
    n00, n01, n02, n03,
    n04, n05, n06, n07,
    n08, n09, n10, n11,
    n12, n13, n14, n15
};

for (Hex h = Hex::n0; h <= Hex::n15; ++h) // Oops! no 'operator ++'
{ /* ... */ }
```

Is easy to get rid of the lack of operators creating a free operator on the same scope:

```
Hex &operator ++(Hex &h)
{
    int r = static_cast<int>(Hex);
    h = static_cast<Hex>(r + 1);
    return h;
}

for (Hex h = Hex::n0; h <= Hex::n15; ++h) // Now the '++h' works!
{
    std::cout << std::dec << int(h) << ": "
              << std::hex << int(h) << '\n';
}
```

But this approach is more a nuisance than a solution, because it can break the value limitation of the enumeration: applying `++h` while `h` equals to `Hex::n15` will set h to he value 16, wich is out of the `Hex` scope of values while `h` is still of the type `Hex`!, This problem is more evident in other enumerations:

```
enum class Prime : int
{
    n00 = 2,   n01 = 3,   n02 = 5,   n03 = 7,
    n04 = 11,  n05 = 13,  n06 = 17,  n07 = 19,
    n08 = 23,  n09 = 29,  n10 = 31,  n11 = 37,
    n12 = 41,  n13 = 43,  n14 = 47,  n15 = 53
};

Prime &operator ++(Prime &p)
{
    // How to implement this?! will I need a lookup table?
    return p;
}
```

This problem was a surprise for me; I was betting that storing an incorrect value into an enumeration value will throw an exception. So, for now I was wondering if there's an elegant way to deal with this enumeration's weaknesses, the goals I want to achieve are:

- Find a comfortable way to use enumeration values in loops.
- Ensuring enumation data consistency between operations.

Additional questions:

- Is there a reason for not throwing an exception when an enumeration data gets a value that is out of its possible values?
- There is a way to deduce the type associated with an enumeration class?, the `int` type in the enumerations `Hex` and `Prime`.

Comment: If you want to iterate then don't use enumerations.

Comment: Feature leak is indeed quite dangerous...

Comment: Arguably, the first problem only manifests because you're absusing enums -- you're using them to enumerate the integers! That's better done with actual integers. The second problem (enumerating primes) is non-trivial.

Comment: what do you mean by "out of its possible values"? enums can have all values that fit in the underlying type the implementation choses (or in case of c++11 that the user chose). So in your case it is int, and you can store all values an int can store.

Comment: Range-checking incurs a runtime cost that is unacceptable in some cases, especially if you know your code will never generate out-of-range values. C++11 provides [`std::underlying_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type).

Comment: Ada and Pascal "do it right", but with a lot of hidden code. As Marcelo mentioned, it incurs a runtime cost. C never had such features. So the way to do it is to use a class as a time instead of an enumeration (which means that all the works falls on you, indeed...) Although you could use a code generator to avoid having to type such classes manually.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Ada and Pascal have a real enumerated type.  C++ doesn't.  Ada and Pascal also have subrange types, and a lot of other stricter type checking than C++.  Different languages, different goals.

Comment: @MarceloCantos so one possible reason for the Additional question #1 is to avoid the runtime costs? I like this answer :)

Answer (score 4):

As you've noticed, `enum` in C++ is *not* an enumerated type,
but something more complex (or more mixed).  When you define an
`enum`, you define in fact two things:

1. An integral type with a legal range sufficient to contain an
   or of all of the enumerated values.  (Technically: the range
   is `2^n - 1`, where `n` is the number of bits necessary to
   hold the largest value.)
2. A series of named constants having the newly defined type.

(I'm not sure what happens with regards to the range if you
explicitly specify an underlying type.)

Given your `enum Prime`, for example, the legal values would be
all integers in the range `[0...64)`, even if all of these
values don't have a name.  (At least if you didn't specifically
say that it should be an `int`.)

It's possible to implement an iterator for enums *without*
initializers; I have a program which generates the necessary
code.  But it works by maintaining the value in an integral type
which is large enough to contain the maximum value plus one.  My
machine generated implementations of `++` on such an enum will
`assert` if you try to increment beyond the end.  (Note that
your first example would require iterating `h` one beyond the
last value: my implementation of the various operators does not
allow this, which is why I use an iterator.)

As to why C++ supports the extended range: `enum` are often used
to define bit masks:

```
enum X
{
    a = 0x01,
    b = 0x02,
    c = 0x04,
    all = a | b | c,
    none = 0
};

X operator|( X lhs, X rhs )
{
    return X((int)lhs | (int)rhs);
}
//  similarly, &, |= and &=, and maybe ~
```

One could argue that this use would be better handled by
a class, but the use of `enum` for it is ubiquitous.

(FWIW: my code generator will not generate the `++`, `--` and
the iterators if any of the enum values has an explicitly
defined value, and will not generate `|`, `&` etc. unless all of
the values have explicitly defined values.)

As to why there is no error when you convert some value outside
the legal range (e.g. 100, for `X`, above) is simply in keeping
with the general philosophy inherited from C: it's better to be
fast than to be correct.  Doing extra range checking would
entail additional runtime cost.

Finally with regards to your last example: I don't see this as
a realistic use of `enum`.  The correct solution here is an
`int[]`.  While the C++ `enum` is rather a mixed breed, I would
only use it as a real enumerated type, or for bit masks (and
only for bit masks because it is such a widely established
idiom).

Comment: C++11 enums with underlying type specified have of course the range of the underlying type.

Comment: @PlasmaHH That would seem logical, but one never knows without actually checking it.  (I can't see any reason to use an `enum` if I want to force a specific underlying type.)

Comment: it probably makes sense when you use enums as constants for bitmasks.

Comment: It makes sense if you want an `enum` type of a well-known size, for example for serialization purposes.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I don't see why.  Without an explicit underlying type, the `enum` is still guaranteed to contain enough bits to contain the _or_ of all of its values, which is all you need.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster You'll convert it to some sort of an integral type anyway, before output.  (I suppose an underlying type of `unsigned char` might be an exception here.  But certainly not any non-character type.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: but you can't control the signedness, can you?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I don't think so, but why would that make a difference?

Comment: the `sizeof` an old-type `enum` is defined by implementation, the only warranty is that it will be an integral type big enough to fit the max value of the `enum`... so an `enum` with max value = 5 could be of 8bits or 32bits, who knows!? but the `sizeof(enum class : int)` or `sizeof(enum class : char)` is well knowed, not implementation defined.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster But you don't care about the size of the object in memory (as long as it is big enough to contain all of the values).  All you're interested in is the size in the serialized format, which is unrelated (except that it too must be large enough to contain all of the values).  And of course, unless the explicit type is a character type, the size is implementation defined anyway (as is the representation).

Comment: @James : Why do you keep telling people what they care about? Maybe _you_ don't care, but maybe the OP does.

Comment: @ildjarn It's an expression.  The size of an enum in memory is irrelevant to serialization.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, I care about the size of the `enum`, supose you have some amount of bytes containing serialized data, supose you perform `memcpy` over this bytes into a `enum` value: `Prime p; memcpy(source, &p, sizeof(p));` if the size of the enum value isn't well known or if it is different in source and destination platforms, the deserialization (even the serialization) will fail... the use of `enum class` with well known underlying type which have well known size, solves this problem, so yes, the size does matters.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Using `memcpy` in serializaiton doesn't work, period (except for byte data).  Even if the `enum` were guaranteed to be implemented as an `int`, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `switch`:

```
class Invalid {};
Prime& operator ++(Prime& p)
{
    switch(p)
    {
        case n00: return n01;
        case n01: return n02;
        case n02: return n03;
        case n03: return n04;
        case n04: return n05;
        case n05: return n06;
        case n06: return n07;
        case n07: return n08;
        case n08: return n09;
        case n09: return n10;
        case n10: return n11;
        case n11: return n12;
        case n12: return n13;
        case n13: return n14;
        case n14: return n15;
        // Here: 2 choices: loop or throw (which is the only way to signal an error here)
        case n15: default: throw Invalid();
    }
}
```

But note that this is *not* the right use of enums. I personally find this error-prone. If you want to enumerate integers, you can use an array of ints to do this, or for the case of prime numbers, a function (in mathematical sense: `int nextPrime(int)`).

Comment: `if (p != n15) return (Hex)((int)p + 1); throw Invalid();`.

Comment: No. Ex: for `p = n09`, `(int)p == 29`, so `(int)p + 1 == 30`, and you don't have any enum value in `Prime` that has the value of 30.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. I didn't read the second half of the question, and I was only thinking of `Hex`.

Comment: "I personally find this error-prone", I agree completly with this. But using a large `switch` is a solution, of course.