# Incrementation and decrementation of “enum class”

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

As we know, incrementation and decrementation of `enum` in C++03 is illegal, because C++03 `enum` may not be continuous. But the C++11 standard introduced the new `enum class` construction, which, according to Wikipedia, is more type-safe because it isn’t built on any simple countable type. So now, if we have a bounded list of values of an enum, can we write something like

```
enum class Colors { Black, Blue, White };
// ...
Colors color = Colors::White;
color++;
```

and will it work correctly (e.g. incrementation of `White` will return `Black` and decrementation of `Black` will return `White`)?

**If we can't write such code, do you know any behavior-like classes either from `boost` or from `Qt` that provide us this feature (correct in- and decrementing)?**

Comment: There's nothing to say that the values of class enums are contiguous. In this respect, they are the same as C++03 enums.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using enum in loops and value consistency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971544/using-enum-in-loops-and-value-consistency)

Comment: Added one more question; please read.

Comment: @juanchopanza: C++03 enums most certainly inherit the C behavior that values are assigned sequentially.  Each enum item without an initializer is the previous item + 1.  If the first has no initializer, it will have the value zero.  This is completely guaranteed and standard, and has been ever since there was a Standard.  see Section 7.2p2

Comment: Who told you that `enum class` isn't built on a base integral type?  The only difference is that now you can optionally choose the base type yourself, instead of the compiler doing it in an implementation-dependent way.

Comment: @benvoigt what I mean is that you can still have jumps in values, as in c++03.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You can explicitly assign values, but skips never happen implicitly.

Comment: @BenVoigt right, so there is no safe, generic way of incrementing enum values.

Comment: The range of representable values for a enum is always continuous. Which values in that range are given explicit names and which are not is completely irrelevant. The fact that one can't use the above operators with enum objct has nothing to do with its continuity.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> will it work correctly

No.  `enum`s are not designed to "wrap around" in the way you describe by default.

And C++11's `enum class` doesn't guarantee contiguous values, the same as you describe for C++03's `enum`.

You can define the wrapping behavior for your particular enum though.  **This solution assumes that the values *are* contiguous**, like the enum you described.

```
enum class Colors { Black, Blue, White, END_OF_LIST };

// Special behavior for ++Colors
Colors& operator++( Colors &c ) {
  using IntType = typename std::underlying_type<Colors>::type
  c = static_cast<Colors>( static_cast<IntType>(c) + 1 );
  if ( c == Colors::END_OF_LIST )
    c = static_cast<Colors>(0);
  return c;
}

// Special behavior for Colors++
Colors operator++( Colors &c, int ) {
  Colors result = c;
  ++c;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: How does this cope with non-contiguous values?

Comment: @juanchopanza only in that we can observe that there are none.

Comment: So compiler accepts `color++` for `enum class` without implementing operators?

Comment: @gxoptg no, there is a recursion going on.

Comment: @DrewDormann added one more question in the end, please read :)

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the heads-up.  Edited.  Recursion removed.

Comment: Is there a way to implement `++` without casts? I can't think of any, but this implementation bothers me. Casts are usually indication of something wrong and there has to be a very good reason for their usage. I would expect the language to allow implementation of `++` to be achievable without forcing to a specific type.

Comment: @icepack I feel your pain.  :)  Perhaps you could consider casts as being "indicative of low-level code" instead of just "wrong".  This is effectively emulating a construct that doesn't exist in C++.  Something that's like an `enum`, but with a contiguous guarantee, and therefore with math ops permitted.

Comment: And what about non-contiguous `enum class`? Iteration over a range of allowed values is a very natural operation and I don't see a way to achieve it even with casts.

Comment: @icepack That's because there isn't. `enum`s are, for that reason, not a particularily useful construct in most situations.

Comment: If you need a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) then just use a [state machine](http://www.boost.org/libs/msm/); trying to use an enum for something it's not intended for is simply counterproductive.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Yes, of course. Use switch; it's tremendously inflexible though, e.g:

switch (c)
{
    case Black: return Blue;
    case Blue: return White;
   etc...

Comment: Is it possible to template this to work for _any_ enum class instead of just one particular `enum class`? If I have 10 different enum classes I would consider this prohibitively complex to maintain all of these `operator++()` overloads for incrementing each type of `enum class`. Note: I'm not so concerned with the wrap-around feature, just the bare increment feature. I'd like to make my increment cleaner [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69762682/4561887).