# How can I overload a postfix operator in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I properly make prefix and postfix operators for any type?

For example, I have this `enum class`:

```cpp
enum class Traffic_light { green, yellow, red };
```

I try to create the operator overloads like:

```cpp
Traffic_light operator++(int)
{
    return Traffic_light::green;
}


Traffic_light operator++()
{
    return Traffic_light::red;
}
```

But this does not work.

```cpp
Traffic_light tl = Traffic_light::green;
++tl; // Error
tl++; // Error
```

> error: no match for ‘operator++’

How does one overload operators in general?

I would like to see a general guide for any type.

Comment: There are a number of questions that are closely related, but I'm not quite sure any are strictly duplicates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295935/can-a-c-enum-class-have-methods and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450914/incrementation-and-decrementation-of-enum-class are enough to see that you can define these operators as non-member functions though.

Comment: Those operators usually modify the relevant object and return either the new value (prefix) or the old (postfix).

Comment: Why are you not actually incrementing but instead returning a specific value based on whether pre/postfix is valled? As for "I expect a general guide for any type", that's too broad and already answered in past questions.

Comment: *I expect a general guide for any type.* That's a pretty rude way of of phrasing your question.

Comment: @super sorry. I didn't mean to. Just reworded the last sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to make the operators non-member functions, you need to pass a `Traffic_light` argument to the operators:

```
Traffic_light operator++(Traffic_light const&, int)
{
    return Traffic_light::green;
}


Traffic_light operator++(Traffic_light const&)
{
    return Traffic_light::red;
}
```

Note that these are returning temporaries, and not references to a particular `Traffic_light` object, which is not how these operators are usually implemented.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hTdMMd).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that

```
enum class Traffic_light { green, yellow, red };

Traffic_light& operator++(Traffic_light& t)
{
    if(t == Traffic_light::red)
        t = Traffic_light::green;
    else
        t = static_cast<Traffic_light>(static_cast<int>(t) + 1);
    return t;
}

Traffic_light operator++(Traffic_light& t, int)
{
    auto temp{t};
    ++t;
    return temp;
}
```

I have implemented it as cyclic. You can read the below link to get the overall information about operator overloading. For instance, which operators cannot be overloaded, etc.

*[Operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)*

Comment: What do you mean by *"as cyclic"*?

Comment: I mean traffic light. It goes `Green, Yellow, Red` then start it over.